# How to mock a class service async axios get with jest in react?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've created a react component which fetches login history details from a rest API and then displays this in a grid. After checking code coverage all lines of the file are covered except line 30 on which the data returned from the API is then set to be rendered in the table accordingly.

```
 const logs = await identityService.getLoginHistory(loginHistoryParams);
                setLogins(logs.loginHistories);
```

Running jest-preview while running the test also shows the component loading successfully but none of the mocked return data being shown on the screen.

I've tried setting up a spy on the service class from which the API call is made to then resolve the response but this doesn't respond with the mockResolvedValue that has been set to be returned (in this case loginHistories). I'm not sure why this is as it's spying on the correct service and method that is defined in the component.

Any assistance would be really helpful, I'm new to unit testing with jest so any best practice examples in response would be really helpful as I'd like to understand how best to mock API calls from services like this as this will be the structure of other API services in my application.

**LoginHistory.test.tsx**

```
const identityServer: IdentityServerService = new IdentityServerService();

const loginHistories: LoginHistoryResponse = {
    loginHistories: [
        {
            username: "admin@test.co.uk",
            name: "Admin",
            loginTime: "2024-02-08T22:22:09.2163700+00:00",
            ipAddress: "20.162.224.241",
            loginStatus: 1,
            browserAgent: "Other"
        },
        {
            username: "user2@test.co.uk",
            name: "User 2",
            loginTime: "2024-02-08T22:19:08.6651460+00:00",
            ipAddress: "20.162.224.241",
            loginStatus: 1,
            browserAgent: "Other"
        }
    ],
    totalRecordsCount: 729504,
    filteredRecordsCount: 729504
};

const mockGetLoginHistories = jest.spyOn(identityServer, "getLoginHistory");
mockGetLoginHistories.mockResolvedValue(loginHistories);

jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
    useTranslation: () => ({ t: (key: string) => key })
}));

const renderComponent = () => {
    return renderWithProviders(<LoginHistoryPage />, {
        preloadedState: {}
    });
};

describe("LoginHistory Page Tests", () => {
    
    it("renders the login history page component", async () => {
        renderComponent();
        const adminUser = await screen.findByText("Admin");
        const user2 = await screen.findByText("User 2");

        expect(adminUser).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(user2).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

**LoginHistoryPage.tsx**

```
const LoginHistoryPage = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const [logins, setLogins] = useState<LoginHistoryData[]>([]);
    const columns = loginHistoryColumns(t);
    const identityService = useMemo(() => new IdentityServerService(), []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const loginHistoryParams: LoginHistoryParams = {
                    username: null,
                    fromDate: null,
                    toDate: null,
                    skip: 0,
                    take: 20,
                    sortByField: "loggedInTime",
                    orderByAscending: false
                };
                const logs = await identityService.getLoginHistory(loginHistoryParams);
                setLogins(logs.loginHistories);
            } catch (error) {}
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [identityService]);

    return (
        <Box className="page-wrapper">
            <Box className="page-header">
                <Typography variant="h1">{t("LoginHistory.Title")}</Typography>
            </Box>

            <DataGrid
                autoHeight
                rows={logins}
                columns={columns}
                initialState={{
                    pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 20 } }
                }}
                getRowId={(row: LoginHistoryData) => row.username + row.loginTime}
                pageSizeOptions={[10, 20, 30]}
            />
        </Box>
    );
};

export default LoginHistoryPage;
```

**IdentityServer.service.ts:**

```
export interface IIdentityService {
    getLoginHistory(
        filterDetails: LoginHistoryParams
    ): Promise<LoginHistoryResponse>;
}

export default class IdentityServerService implements IIdentityService {
    private axios: AxiosInstance;
    private authService: AuthService;

    constructor() {
        this.authService = new AuthService();

        const headers: AxiosRequestConfig = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
            },
            responseType: "json"
        };

        this.axios = axios.create({
            baseURL: config.IdentityServerEndpoint,
            ...headers
        });

        // Bind interceptors
        this.axios.interceptors.request.use(this.requestInterceptor.bind(this));
    }

    private async requestInterceptor(
        config: AxiosRequestConfig
    ): Promise<AxiosRequestConfig> {
        try {
            const token = await this.authService.getAccessToken();
            config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
            return config;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }

    public async getLoginHistory(
        filterDetails: LoginHistoryParams
    ): Promise<LoginHistoryResponse> {
        try {
            const response = await this.axios.post<LoginHistoryResponse>(
                "/login-histories/organisation/login-history",
                filterDetails,
                {
                    params: {
                        "api-version": 2
                    }
                }
            );
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: 14/02/24
I'm still having a lot of trouble with this, I've tried altering my test to below as well and tried spying on the service and method but still having no luck as no data seems to be set on the screen when I run my test with jest-preview.

```
jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
    useTranslation: () => ({ t: (key: string) => key })
}));

const renderComponent = () => {
    return renderWithProviders(<LoginHistoryPage />, {
        preloadedState: {}
    });
};

describe("LoginHistory Page Tests", () => {
    let identityService: IdentityServerService;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        // Initialize IdentityServic
        identityService = new IdentityServerService();
        const loginHistories: LoginHistoryResponse = {
            loginHistories: [
                {
                    username: "admin@test.co.uk",
                    name: "Admin",
                    loginTime: "2024-02-08T22:22:09.2163700+00:00",
                    ipAddress: "20.162.224.241",
                    loginStatus: 1,
                    browserAgent: "Other"
                },
                {
                    username: "user2@test.co.uk",
                    name: "User 2",
                    loginTime: "2024-02-08T22:19:08.6651460+00:00",
                    ipAddress: "20.162.224.241",
                    loginStatus: 1,
                    browserAgent: "Other"
                }
            ],
            totalRecordsCount: 729504,
            filteredRecordsCount: 729504
        };

        // Set up the spy after initializing IdentityService
        jest.spyOn(identityService, "getLoginHistory").mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(loginHistories));
    });

    it("render component", async () => {
        renderComponent();
    });
});
```

**Update 15/02/23**
I've had a little bit of success with jest.spyon in terms of getting tests to pass returning data but this still doesn't seem to affect the api call being made on the component? The third test fails as logs is [] and no data seems to be set? I've tried using a before each and calling the mock and resolving it but this still doesn't render any of the mock data on the page?

```
import { renderWithProviders } from "../../utils/test-utils";
import IdentityServerService from "../../API/IDS/IdentityServer.service";
import LoginHistoryPage from "./LoginHistory";
import { screen } from "@testing-library/react";

jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
    useTranslation: () => ({ t: (key: string) => key })
}));

let identityServer = new IdentityServerService();

const renderComponent = () => {
    return renderWithProviders(<LoginHistoryPage />, {
        preloadedState: {}
    });
};

describe("test", () => {
    it("calls fetchLoginHistory and returns a login history response", async () => {
        const getLoginHistoryMock = jest.spyOn(identityServer, "getLoginHistory");
        getLoginHistoryMock.mockResolvedValue({
            loginHistories: [
                {
                    username: "admin@test.co.uk",
                    name: "Admin",
                    loginTime: "2024-02-08T22:22:09.2163700+00:00",
                    ipAddress: "20.162.224.241",
                    loginStatus: 1,
                    browserAgent: "Other"
                },
                {
                    username: "user2@test.co.uk",
                    name: "User 2",
                    loginTime: "2024-02-08T22:19:08.6651460+00:00",
                    ipAddress: "20.162.224.241",
                    loginStatus: 1,
                    browserAgent: "Other"
                }
            ],
            totalRecordsCount: 729504,
            filteredRecordsCount: 729504
        });

        const response = await identityServer.getLoginHistory({
            username: null,
            fromDate: null,
            toDate: null,
            skip: 0,
            take: 20,
            sortByField: "loggedInTime",
            orderByAscending: false
        });

        expect(response.loginHistories.length).toEqual(2);
    });

    it("renders the component", async () => {
        renderComponent();
    });

    // Test fails as logs is [] and thus no data is set on the page
    it("finds logs on page", async () => {
        const adminName = await screen.findByText("Admin");
        expect(adminName).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Update 12/03/2024
Issue is still persisting, I've tried refactoring the test which returns data but this still isn't reflected in the UI as no text is on the screen in the grid.

```
jest.mock("../../API/IDS/IdentityServer.service");

jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
    useTranslation: () => ({ t: (key: string) => key })
}));

const renderComponent = () => {
    return renderWithProviders(<LoginHistoryPage />, {
        preloadedState: {}
    });
};

describe("test", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        (IdentityServerService as jest.Mock).mockClear();
    });

    it("checks if getLoginHistory calls the APIRequest method", async () => {
        // Mock implementation for getLoginHistory
        const mockLoginHistory = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
            loginHistories: [
                {
                    username: "admin@test.co.uk",
                    name: "Admin",
                    loginTime: "2024-02-08T22:22:09.2163700+00:00",
                    ipAddress: "20.162.224.241",
                    loginStatus: 1,
                    browserAgent: "Other"
                },
                {
                    username: "user2@test.co.uk",
                    name: "User 2",
                    loginTime: "2024-02-08T22:19:08.6651460+00:00",
                    ipAddress: "20.162.224.241",
                    loginStatus: 1,
                    browserAgent: "Other"
                }
            ],
            totalRecordsCount: 729504,
            filteredRecordsCount: 729504
        });

        // Replace the implementation of getLoginHistory with the mock
        (IdentityServerService as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => ({
            getLoginHistory: mockLoginHistory
        }));

        const test = new IdentityServerService();
        const result = await test.getLoginHistory({
            username: null,
            fromDate: null,
            toDate: null,
            skip: 0,
            take: 20,
            sortByField: "loggedInTime",
            orderByAscending: false
        });

        // Expect that getLoginHistory is called once
        expect(mockLoginHistory).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(result).toBeDefined();
        await act(async () => {
            renderComponent();
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

[image]